# ASP.NET FileUpload : not work if there's validator?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

i've the following code:

```
   <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upPanelFoto">
                    <ContentTemplate>

                        <asp:FileUpload onChange="CaricaFileImmagine();" ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" />
                        &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnCaricaImmagine" runat="server" Text="Carica" CssClass="Pulsanti" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCaricaImmagine" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In the same page i've some asp.net fieldvalidator (to validate other field). 
When i click "btnCaricaImmagine" that function never is called, and field validator appear on the screen...

How can i do to load my file ?
Thanks

Comment: Please also check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797190/file-uploading-in-ajax-updatepanel-without-full-postback

Comment: as file not upload when in update panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validator will need to be within the update panel, as will whatever control it is validating.

However, there isn't much point putting a file upload in an update panel as it cause a full postback anyway (hence why you've used the postback trigger). Look at the [AsyncFileUpload](http://www.asp.net/%28S%28fu2l2uzphr2u3u45q2dnez55%29%29/ajax/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx) control or [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org/) for async uploads.

Comment: i'm trying also with AsyncFileUpload but it still don't work... mmmm

Comment: Did you put the `AsyncFileUpload` inside an UpdatePanel? It shouldn't be in one. It still won't fire your validator control's events though.