# Synchronous postback with Telerik Radgrid in updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, telerik, radgrid

I have a RadGrid with a custom edit form (`FormTemplate`). The grid is in an `UpdatePanel` for asynchronous postbacks, as changing the selection in drop down lists and checkboxes needs to enable or disable other controls on the form. (Updating the controls synchronously is not acceptable to the user.)

As part of the edit form, I have a `FileUpload` control, but this does not upload the files when in an update panel.

I have tried adding the Insert/Update button as a `PostBackTrigger` on the `UpdatePanel`, but this causes an error on page load, as the `UpdatePanel` cannot find the control (the edit form is not open on load).

Is there a way to add/remove the trigger at runtime when the form is opened/closed?
Or is it possible to have the `FileUpload`s work with the async-postback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a demo on the Telerik site that shows how to upload the files.

By using a `RadAjaxPanel`, `RadCodeBlock` and `RadScriptManager` with `RadUpload`s instead of `FileUpload`s it is possible to detect on the client side whether files have been selected for upload.
If there are files to upload, the AJAX postback can be disabled during the upload.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/raduploadinajaxifiedgrid/defaultcs.aspx?product=upload&RadUrid=cde8a81e-0eb1-49ca-8c31-4dba37da90c4

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have problem with is as FileUpload is in the list of controls that are not compatible with update panel (for more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx#using_the_FileUpload_Control_with_the_UpdatePanel_control)). One workaround for you could be [swfupload](http://swfupload.org/). Another option is to use this jQuery plugin http://www.plupload.com/example_all_runtimes.php as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797190/file-uploading-in-ajax-updatepanel-without-full-postback)