# FileUpload in Autogenerate Form postback

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, auto-generate

I have a problem. I have a Dynamic form  created in `asp.net`. Generally it has `fileupload companent` . In This time page postback is fire than form generated again and selected file is disappear. My question is how to hold this file in memory?

Am I hold this folder in fileselecting?

Have you any idea for this?

Comment: Did you add the control in postback too?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to security in asp.net. You do not have the ability to specify the value of the file upload and a postback will clear it. You could take care of this by doing thing asynchronously. Try using the AsyncFileUpload control in the AjaxToolKit. You can read about how to use it at http://www.kruegerwebdesign.com/blog/async-file-uploading-using-asp-net.

Comment: Thanks But it is not possible now .All System is running auto generate integration of ajaxtoolkit very difficult.I search simple way for this.May be future the next versions make AsyncFileUpload .

Comment: What about having the file automatically upload to the server and just displaying a label like with gmail. A more detailed explanation can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797190/file-uploading-in-ajax-updatepanel-without-full-postback?rq=1